# Why can't a class extend an enum?

Tags: java, inheritance, syntax, enums, jls

I am wondering why in the Java language a `class` cannot extend an `enum`.

I'm not talking about an `enum` extending an `enum` (which can't be done, since java doesn't have multiple inheritance, and that `enum`s implicitly extend `java.lang.Enum`), but a class that `extends` an `enum` in order to only add extra methods, not extra enumeration values.

Something like:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    ASD(5),
    QWE(3),
    ZXC(7);
    private int number;
    private asd(int number)
    {
        this.number=number;
    }
    public int myMethod()
    {
        return this.number;
    }
}

class MyClass extends MyEnum
{
    public int anotherMethod()
    {
        return this.myMethod()+1;
    }
}
```

To be used like this:

```
System.out.println(MyClass.ASD.anotherMethod());
```

So, can anyone provide a rationale (or point me to the right JLS section) for this limitation?

Comment: Because `enum`s are `final` by default. You can't extend from a `final` class.

Comment: I think he wants to know "why are they final - is there a reason they must be, or should be, final"

Comment: @user949300 this is easy to find by using a SEO like google =\

Comment: Why not just write a static method that takes a `MyEnum` argument instead?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, there are many workarounds, but I'm curious about good reasons why it has been chosen not to allow to do it the way I showed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an answer to *why they did it this way* comes from this question:

In your example, how would you instantiate a MyClass?  Enums are never explicitly instantiated (via a `new MyEnum()`) by the user.  You'd have to do something like `MyClass.ASD` but not sure how that would work.

Basically, I don't know what syntax would work for your proposed addition.  Which is probably why they made them final etc...

EDIT ADDED

If the author of the original Enum planned ahead (unlikely), and you are not worried too much abut thread safety, you could do something like this:  (BTW, I'd probably scream at anybody who actually did this in production code, YMMV)

```
public enum ExtendibleEnum {

   FOO, BAR, ZXC;

   private Runnable anotherMethodRunme;  // exact Interface will vary, I picked an easy one
                           // this is what gets "injected" by your other class

   public void setAnotherMethodRunMe(Runnable r) {  // inject here
      anotherMethodRunme= r;
   }

   public void anotherMethod() {  // and this behavior gets changed
      anotherMethodRunme.run();
   }
}
```

Comment: I was about to make yours the accepted answer ...but then I saw your edit, and screamed a little ^_^

Comment: ...but now thanks to you I fancy the thought of function-pointers and passing around chunks of code :)

Comment: I'm usually pretty restrained on stuff like this, but I've been reading, and enjoying, "Making Java Groovy".  So I blame that for making me more "functional" lately...  :-)

Answer (score 13):

You can't extend an `enum`. They are implicitly `final`. From [JLS § 8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> An enum type is implicitly `final` unless it contains at least one enum constant that has a class body.

Also, from [JLS §8.1.4 - Superclasses and Subclasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4):

> It is a compile-time error if the `ClassType` names the class `Enum` or any invocation of it.

Basically an `enum` is an enumerated set of pre-defined constants. Due to this, the language allows you to use enums in `switch-cases`. By allowing to extend them, wouldn't make them eligible type for switch-cases, for example. Apart from that, an instance of the class or other enum extending the enum would be then also be an instance of the enum you extend. That breaks the purpose of `enum`s basically.

Comment: Yes, but I wonder why: can you provide a rationale for them to be implicitly `final`? My point is that it would be better if they weren't :)

Comment: @UnaiVivi because the specification say so?

Comment: @UnaiVivi Well think about the purpose of enums. And then think, that when you are allowed to extend an enum, you would basically be voiding the purpose.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Of course it does, otherwise it would compile. Why does the specification say so? When writing the JLS they weren't throwing there random choices, most (if not all) decisions had a good reason; that's why I'm asking for the rationale behind that.

Comment: Nice edit to include the switch-case example of why extending an enum might not work.

Comment: @UnaiVivi probably you should email James Gosling about instead of asking here :). You will only receive mere opinions about.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza sorry, he's already received two good reasons, not opinions, for why things were designed the way they are.  This is a case where God (i.e. Gosling) did not have a choice in making the universe.  (Google Einstein for original quote)

Comment: @user949300 since Java 7 you can also use `switch` on plain `String`s, so the `switch` reason IMO falls. Also, the `enum`s are by definition constants, and a constant should not be extended nor modified, and IMO this is a stronger reason to have enums.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yeah that was what I wanted to convey from that point.

Comment: @RohitJain [Regarding your edit] Well, in my imaginary JLS, `class`es extending enums could not add extra enumeration values (only provided by the `enum`) so the switch would still operate on the original enum's costants, but then again the enum would carry the extra methods provided by the extending class.

Answer (score 8):

In ancient days of pre Java 1.5 you would probably do enums like this:

```
public class MyEnum {

public static final MyEnum ASD = new MyEnum(5);
public static final MyEnum QWE = new MyEnum(3);
public static final MyEnum ZXC = new MyEnum(7);

private int number;

private MyEnum(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public int myMethod() {
    return this.number;
    }

}
```

There are two important things about this figure:

- private constructor that will not allow to instantiate the class from outside
- actual "enum" values are stored in static fields

Even if it's not final when you'll extend it, you'll realize that compiler requires an explicit constructor, that in other turn is required to call super constructor which is impossible since that one is private. Another problem is that the static fields in super class still store object of that super class not your extending one. I think that this could be an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of an enum is to create a *closed* set of possible values. This makes it easier to reason about what a value of that enum type is -- easier for you the programmer, and also easier for the compiler (this closedness is what lets it handle enums efficiently in switches, for instance). Allowing a class to extend an enum would open up the set of possible values; at that point, what does the `enum` buy you that a regular `class` wouldn't?

Comment: Well, in my imaginary JLS, `class`es extending enums could not add extra enumeration values (only provided by the actual `enum`) so the set of constants would still remain closed and unextended, but then again the enum would carry the extra methods provided by the extending class.

Comment: Well, you _can_ already define abstract methods in an enum and have each enum value be an anonymous class that implements that method. But if you want a named class, how would you instantiate it without extending the `enum` values?

Answer (score 2):

May I also add that we can emulate Extensible enums using interfaces.

From Joshua Bloch's brilliant book

http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq=mulate+extensible+enums+with+interfaces&source=bl&ots=yYKhIho1R0&sig=vd6xgrOcKr4Xhb6JDAdkxLO278A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XyBgUqLVD8-v4APE6YGABg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=mulate%20extensible%20enums%20with%20interfaces&f=false

or

http://jtechies.blogspot.com/2012/07/item-34-emulate-extensible-enums-with.html

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of an enum is to create a closed set of possible values. This makes it easier to reason about what a value of that enum type is so the set of constants would still remain closed and unextended, but then again the enum would carry the extra methods provided by the extending class.